# React Test: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: undefined

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, redux, jsdom

Hello I'm learning React/redux

I created a todo app it works fine, but when I try to write a component test with jsdom it shows me this error, spent some time but could not figured out the problem:

the component (it's just a textfield + button)

```
import React from 'react'
import {addTodo} from '../actions'
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

let inputText

class AddTodo extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context){
        super(props, context)
    }

    render(){
        const {text, handleAdd} = this.props
        return (
            <div>
                Text:  
                <input type='text' ref={node=>{ inputText=node}} /> <button onClick={()=>handleAdd(inputText.value)} >Add </button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

 const handleAdd = (text)=>{
           dispatch(addTodo(text))
        }

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) =>{
    return {
        handleAdd: (text)=>{
           dispatch(addTodo(text))
        }
    }
}

AddTodo = connect(null,mapDispatchToProps)(AddTodo)

export default AddTodo
```

The spec.js

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import {
    renderIntoDocument,
    scryRenderDOMComponentsWithTag,
    Simulate
} from 'react-addons-test-utils'
import {AddTodo} from '../../src/containers/AddTodo'
import {expect} from 'chai'

describe('Add todo', ()=>{
    it('render the button and text field', ()=>{
        const component = renderIntoDocument(<AddTodo />);
        const button = scryRenderDOMComponentsWithTag(component, 'button');
        const input = scryRenderDOMComponentsWithTag(component, 'input');
        expect(button.length).to.be(1);
        expect(input.length).to.be(1);
    }) 
})
```

The error:

```
Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exporting component as default export:

```
export default AddTodo
```

But importing it as named export

```
import {AddTodo} from '../../src/containers/AddTodo'
```

So AddTodo is undefined.

Change your import to:

```
import AddTodo from '../../src/containers/AddTodo'
```